# Using scala vararg methods in java

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

Why do all scala vararg methods, when used from java, seem to accept a Seq of variables, and can't be used as java native vararg methods. Is this a bug?

For instance, `Buffer` has method `def append(elems: A*): Unit`. But in java it has another signature: `void append(Seq<A>)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a bug.  It is a design choice that favors vararg use within Scala over interoperability with Java.  For example, it allows you to pass a `List` into a Scala varargs method without having to convert it to an `Array` on the way.

If you need to use Scala varargs from Java, you should create some scala Seq instead.  You can, for example, write a Java wrapper to get an array automatically created, and then use the `genericWrapArray` method from the `Predef` object.

Comment: For more details, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060377/how-to-use-scala-varargs-from-java-code

Answer (score 17):

If you control the scala code you can use @varargs to make it generate a java-compatible varags method, e.g. `@varargs def append(elems: A*): Unit = {}`

Answer (score -6):

you can easily cast a `Seq` in varargs using `:_*`. For example :

```
val b = collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]
b.append(List(1, 2):_*)
```

so this avoid code duplication in the collection API.

You can also simply use `appendAll` :

```
b.appendAll((List(1, 2))
```

Comment: Well, yes, I can, but how does that answer my question?))

Comment: I've just modified my answer.

Comment: The problem is not that Seq can't be casted to varargs in scala. The problem is that I have to create a Seq in Java to use a method with varargs.

Comment: Downvoted as you are still answwering a different question than the one asked.